# Jboss AP6 Transaction Manager Implementation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jboss, jta

I'm just starting to learn Jboss AP6 and I have a few questions:
I created Local Tx Datasource (MySql Database)and can access it in my code using JNDI.

Now I would like to create kind of Transaction Management resource inside of my Jboss AP.

1) Is there any JTA feature built in Jboss AP6?

2) Can I apply it to my local DataSource which I created?

3) Can you please point me to any documentation which explains how to configure it and use it in my code, ot is there any article which coversthese topics in depth?

I googled it for some period of time, but haven't found any useful documentation. I don't want to use Spring/Hibernate out of the box solution just Mysql and plain JTA.

Answer (score 1):

1. JBoss AP6 support JTA 1.1
2. Yes you can
3. If you declareLocalTxDatasource, this is mean, than whenever you get
   connection from this datasource  this connection will participate in "current"        transaction.

If you want to manupulate  transaction yourself, without EJB for example, you must enject TransactionManager from JNDI.
Example

```
TransactionManager tm = (TransactionManager)context.lookup("java:/TransactionManager");
tm.begin();
try{
  DataSource ds = context.lookup("java:/testDS");
  connection = ds.getConnection()
  //do useful work
  connection.close();
  tm.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
  tm.rollback()
}
```